# Linker error when trying to create a Windows GUI application in assembly using NASM and GCC

Tags: windows, assembly, gcc, nasm

I am trying to create a simple Windows GUI application using assembly language (NASM) and GCC for linking. My goal is to display a MessageBox using the Windows API functions. However, I am encountering linker errors and I need assistance in resolving them.

**Code:**

```
section .data
    caption db 'Hello, Windows!', 0
    message db 'This is a simple GUI application written in assembly.', 0

section .text
    global _start

    extern _MessageBoxA@16, _ExitProcess@4

    _start:
        ; Set up parameters for MessageBoxA function
        push 0        ; hWnd (NULL for message box)
        push message  ; lpText
        push caption  ; lpCaption
        push 0        ; uType (MB_OK)

        ; Call MessageBoxA function
        call _MessageBoxA@16

        ; Clean up the stack
        add esp, 16

        ; Exit the process
        push 0
        call _ExitProcess@4
```

**Commands used for assembly and linking:**

```
nasm -f win32 -o file.obj file.asm
gcc -m32 -o file.exe file.obj -luser32 -lkernel32
```

**Error Message:**

```
file.obj:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_MessageBoxA@16'
file.obj:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `_ExitProcess@4'
```

Comment: Works here with mingw32 and `-nostartfiles`. 64 bit mingw might do something differently even with `-m32`. Verify the libraries are found. Check the symbol names in the libraries with `nm`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Sorry i had to mention that i'm on windows i can't use `nm`.

Comment: You can use `nm`. Very likely you even have it installed since it comes with binutils which you must have since `gcc` depends on `as` and `ld` which are also part of binutils.